# Unity 3D Image ending points

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3D tour for cardboard. I'm putting my 3d image inside a sphere with a shader but I've noticed this problem. The ending point of image is very visible and disturbing.

And middle of the image is looking kinda wavey and distorted.

[image]

Comment: This is a site for specific programming-related issues. Maybe you should ask the question here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just use a seamless texture or make one with Photoshop. for more info search seamless textures in google.

Comment: Thank you for your answer can you explain a bit more what does seamless texture mean ?

Comment: watch this video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNdbxEEQ9no]